# How re-deploy Cloud Functions affect event queue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

It takes several minutes to re-deploy Cloud Functions. What happens to the events triggered during deployment? Are they queued somewhere and to be processed after deployment, or completely lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events should be queued.  Behind the scenes, Cloud Functions uses a pubsub queue to deliver events generated by various event providers.  It's intended that this queue is not lost when a function is redeployed.

Currently, however, Cloud Functions is in beta and there are no guarantees about availability.